# Save data in Models where field name comes from a variable

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to save data in models where fieldname stored in a variable but while storing it is giving error of  `invalid keyword argument`

**my code :**

```
field = request.POST['creationLanguage']
title = Translation.objects.create(field = request.POST['title'])
```

Here field stores the field name for model Translation but how I store data with this dynamic field_name .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `kwargs` magic:

```
field = request.POST['creationLanguage']
value = request.POST['title']
title = Translation.objects.create(**{field: value})
```

Comment: Yes , It works . But one more thing what is the alternative for this  `title.field` , to get value stored in that field after saving ?

Comment: Yes, `getattr()` is a common solution for getting the object's attribute by name.